# how to fill DataTable from stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to execute a stored procedure with parameters, and get the results into a `DataTable`; but after execution, I get this:

[this is the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zkixx.png)

I can get `IDataRecord` but I can't `IDataReader` - why? What do I miss? Thanks

```
public DataTable ExecuteProcedureTest(string storedProcedure, Dictionary<Filter, object> filterValue)
{
    var parameters = GetParams(filterValue);

    var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["testconn"].ConnectionString);

    var cmd = sqlConnection.CreateCommand(); 

    SqlDataReader reader;
    IDataReader dataReader;
    IDataRecord[] dataRecords;

    var table = new DataTable();

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = storedProcedure;

    foreach (var item in parameters)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(item);
    }

    try
    {
        sqlConnection.Open();
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        dataRecords = reader.OfType<IDataRecord>().ToArray();
        table.Load(reader);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        sqlConnection.Dispose();
    }

    //var count = dataRecords.Count();
    return table;
}
```

Comment: This call `dataRecords = reader.OfType<IDataRecord>().ToArray();` read all records. There is nothing left in the reader for `table.Load(reader);` to work with.

Comment: So that is example when i try everything what i know. So is the same result when i remove that line of code. And please stop giving negative point before then user answer on your comment :S :S

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to fill a `DataTable` from a `SqlCommand`, use a [`SqlDataAdapter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of a `SqlDataReader`.  Here is a handy extension method:

```
public static class SqlExtensions
{
    public static DataTable ExecuteDataTable(this SqlCommand command)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        using (SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
        {
            dataAdapter.Fill(table);
        }
        return table;
    }
}
```

Then from your code you can use it like this:

```
try
{
    sqlConnection.Open();
    table = cmd.ExecuteDataTable();
}
finally
{
    sqlConnection.Dispose();
}
```